# ios syntax for interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Whats the difference between the following pieces of code from objective C stand point?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic) AnotherClass *obj;
@end
```

and

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@property (nonatomic) AnotherClass *obj;
}
@end
```

??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one is incorrect. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 5):

The `{ }` are the area where instance variables are defined. But in modern Objective-C they are not needed in the `@interface` section in order to define instance variables (you can now do that in the `@implementation` section), and they were *never* needed if, as is the case here, there are *no* instance variables being defined. So what I would suggest you do is remove the `{ }` altogether. They are evidently just confusing you, and they serve no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Second one is the correct one. The space between the brackets are only for instance variables e.g.:

NSMutableArray *array

But below that is for methods and properties.